# WP8 Webbrowser control - css vertical-align:middle; not working

Tags: html, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I am working on `Windows Phone 8 app` I have this HTML in my `WebBrowser Control`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta content="width = device-width" name="viewport">
      <style type="text/css">
        #Geo
        { 
        text-shadow:0pt 1.4pt #ffffff; 
        font-family:MyCustomFont;
        font-size:14.0pt; 
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height: normal;
        }  
        #p1
        {
        font-family:MyCustomFont;
        text-align: left; 
        color:#F19B11;
        } 
        #p2
        {
        font-family:MyCustomFont;
        text-align:left; 
        font-size:95%; 
        padding-left: 1.2em;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body id="Geo">
    <p id="p1">
      <img src="image.png" width="60px" height="60px" align="absmiddle"></img>&nbsp;<b>Definition</b>
    </p>
    <ul style="margin-left: 0; padding-left: 1.2em;">
      <li>blah blah ablah blah blah .</li>
      <li>some text some text some text some text some text some text.</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Above Html there are two issues:

- The text which is to right of `image.png` is not `vertically center`
- The bullets are not proper - its starts to extreme left

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please add doctype tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If your html code does't has a doctype tag, WebBrowser Control will render it under quirk mode.